# which book teach Prism for WPF?

Tags: wpf, prism

which book teach Prism for WPF? Any recommendation?

Comment: eBook from official site http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=42572

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get started from here -

[Prism 2.1 on codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/Prism21WPF.aspx)

[Prism 4 on codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/Prism4AppChecklist.aspx)

Also what better place than MSDN -

[Prism 2.x](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648611.aspx)

[Prism 4](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg406140.aspx)

[Prism 4 book as PDF](http://compositewpf.codeplex.com/releases/view/55580)

[Prism 4 Book on Amazon (book form of MSDN)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/073565610X)

Comment: Download eBook from official site http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=42572